# MVC dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I populate @HTML.dropdownlist or @HTML.dropdownlistfor from SQL Server database using linq and MVC Model in C#?  I've seen a lot of examples that use ViewData, but I would like to use model.  I think my hangup is getting the data from the database and into a list that can be used in the view.

A simple yet detailed example is what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends, are you using EF, or oledb calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make you an sample with three actors of pattern

View

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("YourControl", Model.YourSource)%>
```

Controller

```
IEnumerable<YourEntity> result =
                            from item in GetListSample()
                            select new YourEntity
                            {
                                Text = item.Name,
                                Value = item.Value
                            };
  model.YourSource= result;
```

Model

```
public class YourModel
{
    public IEnumerable<YourEntity> YourSource{ get; set; }
}
```

Note : You must inject your model in the view, when you create your view

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example for the sql, but I can help you with the rendering to a page with MVC

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestPortal.Areas.JB.Controllers
{
    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /JB/Example/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.Example.ExampleIndex output = new Models.Example.ExampleIndex();
            output.DropDownData.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "One",
                Value = "1"
            });

            output.DropDownData.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "Two",
                Value = "2"
            });


            return View(output);
        } 

    }
}
```

ExampleIndex.cs : note it is always good to build a view model to pass data to the view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestPortal.Areas.JB.Models.Example
{
    public class ExampleIndex
    {
        public ExampleIndex()
        {
            this.DropDownData = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> DropDownData
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model TestPortal.Areas.JB.Models.Example.ExampleIndex

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@Html.RFSSelect("DropDownId", Model.DropDownData)
```